# Ho to refresh view and tableview, and checkmark a default setting cell on load?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

I'm currently setting up the "Settings/preferences" side of my first app in iOS. i currently have NSUserdefaults setup so that the app remembers the users preferences. I have 2 questions:

Firstly, once a particular cell has been selected it is checkmarked and saved as a default(works), but when i move back to the main setting tableview, i have a label on the cell that it links with that needs to update but doesn't until i move back further to main page, then load settings again. a way to refresh the setting view? Main page(viewcontroller) also has a label that i need to update which doesn't either.

Secondly, when going into say the "measurement tableview with "kph" or "mph". How can i make the cell checkmarked indicating its the current selection from defaults? The current code for  one of the tableview preferences is bellow:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
// Uncheck the previous checked row
if(self.checkedIndexPath)
{
 UITableViewCell* uncheckCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.checkedIndexPath];
 uncheckCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
self.checkedIndexPath = indexPath;

NSLog(@"cell.textLabel.text = %@",cell.textLabel.text);
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:cell.textLabel.text forKey:@"windSpeed"];
[defaults synchronize];
}
```

Comment: Hi can you explain your question in right way? because here somethings is confusing.

Comment: To upadte label on cell you have to reload table data using method [yourtableview reloadData];

Comment: means you want to update label as per your NSUSerDefault value which is checkmark UITableview title

Comment: I think this is a software design question. Can you enumerate the UIViewController subclasses that you use? It should be pretty easy to answer if you provide those.

Comment: If had a quick play with my viewcontroller, and included viewWillLoad method which worked, didn't work for tableview and will have a look at reloadData thanks. Haven't worked out cell checkmark yet either!

Comment: i tried inserting [self.tableView reloadData] in both viewDidLoad and in viewWillAppear in parent and child .m files and neither made any difference to the labels on the parent view updating from the selection made in the child view.

Comment: only thing not working now is the parrent tableview not reloading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess you need to reload your table in  viewWillAppear

Comment: i tried this an it didn't work, i ended up moving my code that populates the cell text to viewWillAppear window and all good.Thx