# Persistently keeping a UITableView selected cell's UIAccessoryType with NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, iphone, nsuserdefaults, uitableview

There are many questions on this topic and I've been trying this for hours with the various options, but I'm in need of some real assistance with this.

The main premise is: I have a `Tab Bar controller` with two tabs; the first is a `Timeline` and the second is the `In-App Settings` (both `table view controllers`). In the `In-App settings`, when I select "Keyboard", I'm taken to another Table view by segue with two static cells: Light and Dark.

What I want to achieve is: When I tap on one of these cells, it puts a `checkmark accessory` view on that `cell`.

Using `NSUserDefaults`, I want to maintain the selected cell and set that cells' accessoryType to checkmark on the next view reload.

I followed this questions' selected answer and while my code allows me to select either the Light or Dark cell; it never maintains that in between reloading.

Here's my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];    
    self.selectedKeyboardCell = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Selected"];

    NSLog(@"The selected keyboard is %@", self.selectedKeyboardCell);

    if([self.checkedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath])
    {
        NSLog(@"Loaded");
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Not Loaded");

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        /*if ([self.selectedKeyboardCell isEqualToString:@"Light"])
        {
            NSLog(@"P");
            if (indexPath.row == 0)
            {
                NSLog(@"Q");
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            }
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"R");
            if (indexPath.row == 1)
            {
                NSLog(@"Z");
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            }
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
*/

    }
```

My `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Uncheck the previous checked row
    if(self.checkedIndexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell* uncheckCell = [tableView
                                        cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.checkedIndexPath];
        uncheckCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    self.checkedIndexPath = indexPath;

    self.selectedKeyboardCell = cell.textLabel.text;

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.selectedKeyboardCell forKey:@"Selected"];

    self.selectedKeyboardTheme = cell.textLabel.text;

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];


    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.selectedKeyboardTheme forKey:@"Keyboard"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

I have a `[self.keyboardTableView reloadData];` in my `viewWillAppear`.

I have commented out some code I've been trying, but no matter how many posts I read, I just cannot find the solution here.

This question talks about shifting code to the viewWillAppear but I have no idea what code he's saying: [Ho to refresh view and tableview, and checkmark a default setting cell on load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353982/ho-to-refresh-view-and-tableview-and-checkmark-a-default-setting-cell-on-load?rq=1)

Problem: I want to select a cell in the Table View and have that cell selected with a checkmark accessory type the next time (and every time this view loads). It's a static table and the text is ONLY ever going to say Light or Dark.

In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, `self.selectedKeyboardCell` accurately tells me whether it's Light or Dark, depending on which cell was selected before the view was loaded. However, how do I say "If Light, set the checkmark on the FIRST cell and remove the checkmark from the second cell and if Dark, set the checkmark on the SECOND cell and remove the checkmark from the first cell".

Update:
For clarity, I am able to select either the Light or Dark static Table view cell and whichever cell I select, the checkmark appears correctly. The problem is when I go to another view and come back to this view, the previously selected cell does not show. I'm saving the selectedCell's `textLabel` to `NSUserDefaults` and in the `NSLog`, it shows me the text of the selected cell but it does not show me the checkmark on the selected cell.

Update Two:
In order to set the default selected cell to Light the first time the app was run, I did the following in the cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
if (!self.selectedKeyboardCell)
{
    self.checkedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
```

Any guidance on this would be seriously appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly your code is a little confusing and it would help, if you had said a little more what actually works. But:

In the `viewWillAppear` you should just set the `self.checkedIndexPath`:

```
if ([self.selectedKeyboardCell isEqualToString:@"Light"])
{
   self.checkedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
}else{
   self.checkedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];
}
[self.keyboardTableView reloadData];
```

right?

Comment: Dear @Nils - my apologies for the lack of clarity in my question but your answer did the job perfectly. I will update my question to ensure there is clarity in there. I did have one quick follow up question though. If I uninstall and reinstall my app, the default cell with the checkmark is "Dark"; I want it to be the "Light" cell (which is indexPathForRow:0. I tried adding that to storyboard, the checkmark to the Light Cell but it didn't make a difference. How (and where) would I set the default selected state (the very first time the app runs) to Light?

Comment: Actually, I've just got it working and have updated my question with Update Two to reflect the code done. I really massive thank you @Nils - You've saved me hours and hours and you've helped me get this working. I really appreciate it. I would up vote you twice if I could.